# why Argument of type 'Pool' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interface'

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

i am trying clean code of nodejs typescript with native mysql query, only there is a problem when calling mysql class to execute query. the following is the source code.

**user-data-source.ts**

```
export interface UserDataSource {
    register(user: UserReqEntity): void;
    getUsers(): Promise<UserResEntiry[]>;
    getUser(kode: string): Promise<UserResEntiry | null>;
    updateUser(kode: string, data: UserReqEntity): void;
    deleteUser(kode: string): void
}
```

**sqldb-wrapper.ts**

```
export interface MYSQLDbWrapper {
    query(queryString?: any, queryConf?: any[] | any): Promise<{ row: any[] }>
}
```

**mysql-user-data-source.ts**

```
export class MYSQLUserDataSource implements UserDataSource {
    private db: MYSQLDbWrapper

    constructor(db: MYSQLDbWrapper) {
        this.db = db
    }

    async register(user: UserReqEntity) {
        await this.db.query(`insert into ${DB_TABLE} (kode, username, email, tgl_lahir, jk, url_photo) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, [user.kode, user.username, user.email, user.tgl_lahir, user.jk, user.url_photo])
    }

    async getUsers(): Promise<UserResEntiry[]> {
        const dbRes = await this.db.query(`select * from ${DB_TABLE}`)
        const res = dbRes.row
        return res
    }

    async getUser(kode?: string): Promise<UserResEntiry | null> {
        const dbRes = await this.db.query(`select * from ${DB_TABLE} where kode = ? limit 1`, [kode!])
        const res = dbRes.row
        return res[0]
    }

    async updateUser(kode?: string, data?: UserReqEntity) {
        await this.db.query(`update ${DB_TABLE} set username = ?, tgl_lahir = ?, jk, url_photo = ? where kode = ?`, [data?.username, data?.tgl_lahir, data?.jk, data?.url_photo, kode])
    }

    async deleteUser(kode?: string) {
        await this.db.query(`delete ${DB_TABLE} where kode = ?`, [kode])
    }

}
```

**connection mysql with pool**

```
async function connMySql() {
    pool = mysql.createPool({
        // connectionLimit: 100,
        user: process.env.USER_MySql,
        host: process.env.HOST_MySql,
        database: process.env.DBNAME_MySql,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD_MySql,
        port: Number(process.env.PORT_MySql),
    })

    return new MYSQLUserDataSource(pool)
}
```

i get error in `return new MYSQLUserDataSource(pool)`

for information error like this, `Argument of type 'Pool' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MYSQLDbWrapper'. The types returned by 'query(...)' are incompatible between these types. Type 'Query' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<{ row: any[]; }>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]`

help me, please, thanks you :D

Answer (score 0):

done.

change
**sqldb-wrapper.ts** to

```
export interface MYSQLDbWrapper {
    query(queryString?: any, queryConf?: any[] | any): Promise<any>
}
```

and import mysql with promise,
so like this,

```
import mysql from 'mysql/promise'
```